# Component not updating on state change with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm using React and React Router. I have all my data fetching and routes defined in App.js.
I'm clicking the button in a nested child component `<ChildOfChild />` which refreshes my data when clicking on a button (passed a function down with Context API) with a fetch request happening in my top component App.js (I have a console.log there so it's fetching on that click for sure). But the refreshed state of data never arrives at the `<ChildOfChild />` component. Instead, it refreshes the old state. What am I doing wrong. And how can I ensure my state within `<Link>`is refreshing on state update.
I expect the `item.name` value to be updated on button click.

**App component**

- has all the routes and data fetching
- uses Reacts Context API, which I use to pass my fetching to child components
- below the basic shape of the App component.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export const FetchContext = React.createContext();
export const DataContext = React.createContext();

const App = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([false, "idle", [], null]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setData([true, "fetching", [], null]);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/sample/`,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `AUTHTOKEN` },
        }
      );
      console.log("APP.js - FETCH DATA", res.data)
      setData([false, "fetched", res.data, null]);
    } catch (err) {
      setData([false, "fetched", [], err]);
    }
  };

 return (
  <Router>
    <DataContext.Provider value={data}>
      <FetchContext.Provider value={fetchData}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/sample-page/" component={Child} />
          <Route exact path="/sample-page/:id" component={ChildOfChild} />
        </Switch>
      </FetchContext.Provider>
    </DataContext.Provider>
  </Router>
  )
}
```

**Child component**

```
import { DataContext } from "../App";

const Child = () => {
  const [isDataLoading, dataStatus, data, dataFetchError] = useContext(DataContext);
  const [projectsData, setProjectsData] = useState([]);
  {
    data.map((item) => (
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/sampe-page/${item.id}`,
          state: { item: item },
        }}
      >
        {item.name}
      </Link>
    ));
  }
```

**Child of Child component**

```
import { FetchContext } from "../App";

const ChildOfChild = (props) => {
    const getData = useContext(FetchContext);
    const [item, setItem] = useState({});
    const [isItemLoaded, setIsItemLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.location.state.item) {
          setItem(props.location.state.item);
          setIsItemLoaded(true);
        }
    }, [props]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => getData()}Refresh Data</button>
            <div>{item.name}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you post the context code?

Comment: If I understand your description you click the button to call `getData` and some state is to be updated in the context and the component rerendered? Please include the relevant context code, provider, etc... to your question. What are you expecting `ChildOfChild` to do when the context is updated?

Comment: @ViniciusKatata I added more code for the `App`component. Especially the `useContext` information.

Comment: What do you do with `data`, it appears to be unused.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you, please give me a moment i will add all of the logic.

Comment: @DrewReese I added all logic. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for now.

Comment: Ah, I see now. `ChildOfChild` is only receiving data via the route transition from `Child` when the link is clicked. If you want `ChildOfChild` to see updated `data` state then it also needs to consume the `DataContext` context.

Comment: Am I using a bad react design? And if yes how should I redesign my logic and structure? What would be the cleanest go-to approach?

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The specific data item that `ChildOfChild` renders is only sent via the route transition from `"/sample-page/"` to `"/sample-page/:id"` and `ChildOfChild` caches a copy of it in local state. Updating the `data` state in the `DataContext` won't update the localized copy held by `ChildOfChild`.

## Suggestion

Since you are already rendering `ChildOfChild` on a path that uniquely identifies it, (recall that `Child` PUSHed to `"/sample-page/${item.id}"`) you can use this `id` of the route to access the specific data item from the `DataContext`. There's no need to also send the entire data item in route state.

Child

Just link to the new page by item `id`.

```
<Link to={`/sampe-page/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</Link>
```

ChildOfChild

Add the `DataContext` to the component via `useContext` hook.
Use `props.match` to access the route's `id` match param.

```
import { FetchContext } from "../App";
import { DataContext } from "../App";

const ChildOfChild = (props) => {
  const getData = useContext(FetchContext);
  const [,, data ] = useContext(DataContext);

  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
  const [isItemLoaded, setIsItemLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { match: { params: { id } } } = props;
    if (id) {
      setItem(data.find(item => item.id === id));
      setIsItemLoaded(true);
    }
  }, [data, props]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getData}Refresh Data<button />
      <div>{item?.name}<div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `useEffect` will ensure that when either, or both, the `data` from the context or the props update that the `item` state will be updated with the latest `data` and `id` param.

Just a side-note about using the `Switch` component, route path order and specificity matter. The `Switch` will match and render ***the first*** component that matched the path. You will want to order your *more* specific paths before *less* specific paths. This also allows you to not need to add the `exact` prop to every `Route`. Now the `Switch` can attempt to match the more specific path "/sample-page/123" before the less specific path "/sample-page".

```
<Router>
  <DataContext.Provider value={data}>
    <FetchContext.Provider value={fetchData}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/sample-page/:id" component={ChildOfChild} />
        <Route path="/sample-page/" component={Child} />
      </Switch>
    </FetchContext.Provider>
  </DataContext.Provider>
</Router>
```

Comment: thank you for your in-depth answer. That is exactly how I ended up doing it, I was wondering if there is no other way to pass states with react-router as therefore I don't see any reason to use state in a Link at all as it's not possible to update the state. I also have to repeat the `find` func for multiple subelements of `item` for subpages. In addition to that. I made it this way `import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";`   `const{ dataId } = useParams();` and included `dataId` in the dependencies of the useEffect function so it updates on route change. You haven't done this.

Comment: @BenjaminK Since the component is directly rendered by a `Route` on the component prop, it receives [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), of which the `match` is one of those. You could surely use the `useParams` hook to get the match params. The issue with sending data via route state is that it is ***very*** transient. It only exists ***during*** the transition and the receiving route's component must save it. I explained why *this* version of the passed state won't be updated.

Comment: @BenjaminK As for the `find` function, if this is a common, repeated pattern, then this is a good candidate for factorization into a utility function so your can make your code more DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself).

Answer (score -1):

I've just rewrote your code here, I've used `randomuser.me/api` to fetch data

Take a look here, it has small typo errors but looks ok here

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-paper-nde5c?file=/src/Child.js

Comment: I appreciate all your effort to put it into a code sandbox, would you mind explaining what you found as an error and your approach to fix it. Because it's not clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: Like I said, it was type errors, examples: `...resh Data<button />` should `...resh Data</button>` instead, `<div>{item.name}<div>` doens´t have closing tag `<div>{item.name}</div>`

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't show anything ui wise. And the typing error exists only here in StackOverflow as I wrote the code simplified here as my production example is way more complex. It's definitely not working.

Comment: `Your sandbox doesn't show anything ui wise`, didnt got it